# Conditional firesbase firestore rules not applying correctly to react app query

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My firestore rules seem to apply for a directly made query just right, but if I use my react web app to do the read query, I don't get permission to read.

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
        allow read: if resource.data.active == true
        && request.time.toMillis() < ( resource.data.timeInSV + 6000000 );
}}
```

This are my read rules in firestore the match /users/{user} block should enable me to read all documents in the collection that have been created within the 100 minute timestamp timespan and which are marked active.

I get a response when cURL`ing, success!

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/NAME/databases/(default)/documents/users/USER_ID
```

But I do not get permission to read from within the react app for my query:

```
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection("users").where("lastname", "==", this.state.lastname.trim().toLowerCase()).where("active", "==", true)
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                var users = {}; 
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                 users[doc.id] = doc.data().firstname
                  }
```

Results in:

```
[Log] Error getting documents:  
– FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions. (main.chunk.js, line 1228)
FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

As soon as I remove the `&& request.time.toMillis()...` from my firestore read rule, I can access all active documents again from the react webapp.
Same goes for the time rule, **it works but only alone**, not in combination with the other condition of the user having to be `active`.

Comment: Could it be that the value of `resource.data.timeInSV` is actually less than `toMillis()`?

Comment: Maybe you need to pass from seconds to millis :`resource.data.timeInSV * 1000;`